# how to turn off Web2py ticketing system?

Tags: web2py

I want to Web2py to just return the error screen/stack-trace... i don't want this ticketing system in place.  how can I turn it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. If you are logged in as administrator and you click on the ticket number, it will open a window with the stack-trace. You can use routes_onerror in routes.py to display a different error page to your user and hide the ticket number if you do not wish to expose it.

Comment: well Google App Engine makes the ticketing system a pain in the arse... so I just wanted to turn it off.   blah... ok i'll find a workaround.  thanks

Comment: Now I understand your problem better. Just use routes.py so that tickets are not displayed and periodically delete everything in the web2py tickets table. For practical purposes if you delete them and you do not see is as if they are not there. ;-)

Comment: One should be able to disable it, at least for local development.

Comment: I don't know if the answer I'm looking for is directly related to this, but I'd like exceptions to be passed through to my debugger when I'm running web2py with it.  So I'd like to be able to disable exception handling altogether.  I haven't found a way to do this as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

I hide tickets from end users in our Web2py production environment by doing the following:

1) In the model (db.py) I test to see if I am in the production environment and if so, I add a variable called hide_ticket to the user's request:

```
# The is_production variable is read from an environment variable earlier.
if settings.is_production:
    request.hide_ticket = True
```

2) Then modify gluon/main.py to this:

```
    if request.hide_ticket:
        http_response = \
            HTTP(500, '<html><body><h1>Request Failed</body></h1></html><!--- IE Needs this' + ('x' * 512) + '--->' )

    else:
        http_response = \
            HTTP(500, rwthread.routes.error_message_ticket %
                 dict(ticket=ticket),
                 web2py_error='ticket %s' % ticket)
```

Instead of this:

```
 http_response = \
                HTTP(500, rwthread.routes.error_message_ticket %
                     dict(ticket=ticket),
                     web2py_error='ticket %s' % ticket)
```

Comment: There's a way to use a custom error template instead of displaying the ticket. Check here,
http://www.web2py.com/AlterEgo/default/show/75